# Suspicious ID in docker daemon logs

Tags: docker, logging, docker-daemon

I'm facing an issue with a docker cluster and looking at the logs I've found a strange log entry:
`Aug  3 02:48:36 <hostname> dockerd: time="2020-08-03T02:48:36.967863272Z" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats <hostname>(59eadb9debca) - netID:o30h5ct285gjcvytl89oaeqi7 leaving:false netPeers:12 entries:24 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"`
I'm saying it's strange because I can't figure out what the ID portion of the log is representing. The docker node itself has another ID and there is no container with that ID running. Checking other nodes they all have similar ids. Is someone aware what this ID represents and how to retrieve it using the docker client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's the name the docker swarm assigns to a peer when working with overlay networks. You can get a list of networks by running

`docker network ls`

in the output you will see one or more networks marked as DRIVER=overlay and SCOPE=swarm, you can then inspect one by running:

`docker network inspect <NETWORK_NAME>`

and in the output you should see a section called `Peers` with a name and ip address, your id should match one of the names.